# EXCEL Cell Value Search On A Separate Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I have been trying to find a solution to this but am unable to.  I have two files with a large amount of data in. One of the columns is ID with a six digit number in each row.

Is there a way that I can click on a cell (contains data: 123456) in the ID Column from File1.xls so that it then opens and highlights the same value (data: 123456) in File2.xls by way of searching file 2? Maybe even vice versa.

Very sorry for not having any attempted code/formula as an example of trying it's just that I have no idea where to start. I can quite easily link it to file 2 but I don't see this method as being efficient, especially due to the number of rows contained within the sheets.

Many thanks to anyone that may be able to help.

Comment: Look into the Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick event.  You could put vba in that to do what you want.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Thank you for the reply.  Not very excel literate and what I just read went straight over my head.